# forma para seleccionar los proximos 2 dias desde la db con mysql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Mi duda es la siguiente, 
mi duda es como puedo mostrar unicamente la columna de la fecha, sin que me salgan todas las demas columnas, mi codigo es el siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM tcsschedule WHERE dddate > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

en el codigo estoy mandando a llamar la tabla tcsschedule donde solo estoy eligiendo la columna dddate en la que estoy ordenando que muetre los registros desde la fecha actual con un intervalo de 2 dias proximos.

Comment: No se si te entiendo.. algo como esto ¿`select dddate FROM ....`?

Comment: ya la edite lo que pasa es que no me explique exactamente lo que no me queda claro hacer

Comment: Igual sigue sin entender, ¿quieres que el `select` solo retorne la columna `ddate`?

Comment: asi es solo quiero que al hacer la consulta solo me muestre la columna dddate pero unicamente con los registros de los 2 proximos dias

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, entiendo que quieres las filas donde `ddate` tenga valores desde hoy hasta los próximos dos días, por ejemplo: entre `2019-06-27` y `2019-06-28`. El primer tema, es que si `ddate` tiene valor de fecha/hora el limite superior `2019-06-28`, no nos sirve ya que todas las fechas de este día, al tener hora, serán mayores. Conviene entonces trabajar con valores únicamente de fecha y hacer un límite no inclusivo a un día más del solicitado.

En primer lugar, veamos los parámetros:

```
SET @Hoy := DATE(NOW());

select 
    @Hoy,
    DATE_ADD(@Hoy, INTERVAL 3 DAY);

╔═══╦════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ # ║ @Hoy       ║ DATE_ADD(@Hoy, INTERVAL 3 DAY) ║
╠═══╬════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 2019-06-27 ║ 2019-06-30                     ║
╚═══╩════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

Y ahora usando esto en tu consulta:

```
SET @Hoy := DATE(NOW()); 
SELECT ddate 
       FROM tcsschedule 
       WHERE dddate >= @Hoy, 
             AND dddate  < DATE_ADD(@Hoy, INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Nota: Al estar obligado a usar más de una vez `NOW()` y al ser ésta una función no determinística (cada vez retorna un valor distinto) es preferible inicializar este valor en una variable `@Hoy`.

Comment: es correcto gracias por la ayuda y una disculpa si no me supe explicar correctamente